# Set angle of sprite (rotate) in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am new in cocos2d game development. I've set a Turret on the screen. When we touch the screen, the turrets fire bullets, but my turret's angle is not set correctly. This code is taken from the raywenderlich tutorial series. Also, bullets are not passing by the touched point.

Below is my code.

[image: Screenshot]

```
 // Determine offset of location to projectile
    CGPoint offset = ccpSub(cointouchLocation,turretArms.position);

    NSLog(@"offset: %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(offset));

    // Bail out if you are shooting down or backwards

    if (offset.x <= 0) return;
    int realX = winSize.width +(turretArms.contentSize.width/2);
    float ratio =  (float) offset.y/(float) offset.x;
    int realY =(realX * ratio) +turretArms.position.y;
    CGPoint realDest = ccp(realX, realY);

    // Determine the length of how far you're shooting
    int offRealX = realX - turretArms.position.x;
    int offRealY = realY - turretArms.position.y;
    float length = sqrtf((offRealX*offRealX)+(offRealY*offRealY));
     float velocity = 480/1;
    float realMoveDuration = length/velocity;




    // Determine angle to face
   float angleRadians = atanf((float)offRealY / (float)offRealX);

   // NSLog(@"angleRadians : %f",angleRadians);
    float angleDegrees = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angleRadians);
    float cocosAngle = -1 * angleDegrees;
    float rotateDegreesPerSecond = 180 / 0.5; // Would take 0.5 seconds to rotate 180 degrees, or half a circle
    float degreesDiff = turret.rotation - cocosAngle;
    float rotateDuration = fabs(degreesDiff / rotateDegreesPerSecond);
    [turret runAction:
     [CCSequence actions:
      [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],
      [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
         // OK to add now - rotation is finished!
         [self addChild:turretArms];
         [turretsAry addObject:turretArms];

         // Release
         [turretArms release];
         turretArms = nil;
     }],
      nil]];

    // Move projectile to actual endpoint
    [turretArms runAction:
     [CCSequence actions:
      [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:realMoveDuration position:realDest],
      [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
         [turretsAry removeObject:node];
         [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
     }],
      nil]];

    turretArms.tag =2;

    //coin delete from window

    for (CCSprite *cmonster in coinmonstersToDelete) {
        // [monster stopAllActions];
        [coinmonstersOnScreen removeObject:cmonster];
        [self removeChild:cmonster cleanup:YES];

    }
```

Comment: Could you include the whole method?

Comment: @SwankSwashbucklers,yes

Comment: I meant it would be nice to know where in the program this code exists.  Is it in the ccTouchBegan method?

Comment: Thanx, for your replay, Ya it's in ccTouchesEnded method.

Comment: If the code is in your ccTouchesEnded method then the code is executed after your finger leaves the screen.  Is this the behavior you want?

Comment: no, it's not problem.it's also put in ccTouchesBegin method.But, i follow raywenderlich tutorial.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44470/discussion-between-renish-dadhaniya-and-swankswashbucklers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if (_nextProjectile != nil) return;

    // Choose one of the touches to work with
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

    // Set up initial location of projectile
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    _nextProjectile = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"projectile2-Hd.png"] retain];


     _nextProjectile.position = ccp(winSize.width/2,20);

    // Determine offset of location to projectile
    CGPoint offset = ccpSub(location, _nextProjectile.position);
     NSLog(@"offset.x : %f",offset.x);
    NSLog(@"offset.x : %f",offset.y);

    // Bail out if you are shooting down or backwards
   if (offset.y <= 0) return;

    int realY = winSize.height - (_nextProjectile.contentSize.width/2);
     float ratio = (float) offset.x / (float) offset.y;
    int realX = (realY * ratio) + _nextProjectile.position.x;
    CGPoint realDest = ccp(realX, realY);

    // Determine the length of how far you're shooting
    int offRealX = realX - _nextProjectile.position.x;
    int offRealY = realY - _nextProjectile.position.y;
    float length = sqrtf((offRealX*offRealX)+(offRealY*offRealY));
    float velocity = 480/1; // 480pixels/1sec
    float realMoveDuration = length/velocity;

    // Determine angle to face
   // float angleRadians = atanf((float)offRealY / (float)offRealX);
    float angleRadians = atanf((float)offRealX / (float)offRealY);

    float angleDegrees = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angleRadians);
   // float cocosAngle = -1 * angleDegrees;
     float cocosAngle = angleDegrees;
    float rotateDegreesPerSecond = 180 / 0.5; // Would take 0.5 seconds to rotate 180 degrees, or half a circle
    float degreesDiff = _player.rotation - cocosAngle;
    float rotateDuration = fabs(degreesDiff / rotateDegreesPerSecond);
    [_player runAction:
     [CCSequence actions:
      [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],
      [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
         // OK to add now - rotation is finished!
         [self addChild:_nextProjectile];
         [_projectiles addObject:_nextProjectile];

         // Release
         [_nextProjectile release];
         _nextProjectile = nil;
     }],
      nil]];

    // Move projectile to actual endpoint
    [_nextProjectile runAction:
     [CCSequence actions:
      [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:realMoveDuration position:realDest],
      [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {
         [_projectiles removeObject:node];
         [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    }],
      nil]];

    _nextProjectile.tag = 2;

  // [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"pew-pew-lei.caf"];
}
```